# RadioGroup across multiple fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, radio-button, radio-group

I'm a bit new to android and I'm trying to create a user interface similar to this:

[image: UI]

Where a user can select a radio button to choose the active item, and there can only be one active item at a time.  I need to generate this list programmatically, as what is in this list will change based on user input.  So far what I have done is create a layout with a radio button followed by and image button (the trash can), and use a list adapter to populate it, all inside a fragment.  While that renders fine, all the radio buttons are individual and not part of a radio group.  But RadioGroup seems to be rather picky and wont work in a relative layout or across multiple instances of a layout.  My attempts to programmatically add the radio button to the radio group haven't been successful, neither has trying to keep a reference to each one in an array list and doing things manually.  Code snippets would be nice, but what I'm looking for is a more experienced android developer to tell me the general object/layout structure they would recommend for achieving this type of interface.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need implement BaseAdapter and a ListView.
Here some samples and tutorials.

http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html

http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/listview-with-custom-adapter.html

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

Comment: I've written a custom list adapter already and it worked great (I actually followed the first guide you linked), my problem is more specifically dealing with the radio buttons in the list.

Comment: You need save the radiobutton checked position, and do a "notifyDataSetChanged" when the user select a radiobutton, compare the position and checked position if is different.

Comment: So in my ArrayAdapter I implement notifyDataSetChanged to handle any user action, and call it from a custom OnCheckedChangeListener I attach to the RadioButton in the adapter's getView?  I'm surprised with how much goes into what I thought would be a simple UI.